# no instalce of constructor "AMA::Product::Product" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm working on an assignment in C++ that uses constructors. The test file that the professor created contains a 3 argument constructor. However, the requirements are only a zero-one constructor where the parameter is optional and a 7 parameter constructor.

Both are already created.

```
// Product.h
Product(char type);                     
Product(const char* sku, const char* address, const char * unit, int onHand, int needed, double beforeTax, bool taxable);


// test.cpp
MyProduct::MyProduct() : Product("", "", "") {}
```

Due to this, VS is complaining that I don't have the correct constructor that matches the argument list.

Any clues?

Comment: I counted 7 non-optional parameters and 3 arguments. What isn't clear?

Comment: Well. That is not clear to me. There's 7 mandatory constructors and the test is calling 3 arguments.

From my understanding, I only declared 2 constructors:

1. Optional 1 parameter constructor
2. 7 Mandatory parameter constructor

I don't understand where 3 fits the picture

Comment: Your prof made a mistake or you missed something in the assignment. Either way the person to ask is the prof.

Comment: Also to update, I noticed that I made the mistake of not defaulting the last 4 parameters of the constructor.

My 7 argument constructor now looks like:

     Product::Product(const char* sku, const char* address, const char * unit, int onHand = 0, int needed = 0, double beforeTax = 0.0, bool taxable = true)

However, the same error persists

Comment: The 'Product::Product' in your comment suggests you might have added the default parameters to the constructor definition. You need to make sure they are instead specified in the constructor declaration (in the header).

Answer (score 0):

You have exactly two options: either you call the constructor with **no parameters** or with **7 parameters**. You are calling it with **3 parameters**, which is neither 0, nor 7.

You have to either provide no parameters or exactly 7 to make it work.

Alternatively you can modify the 7-parameter constructor to have the last 4 of its parameters optional and only then can you call it with only 3 parameters (in this case the compiler will fill in the other 4 for you)

Comment: In this case, I defaulted the last 4 parameters to 0. However, I'm still getting the error that it's not finding a suitable constructor for the 3 parameter constructor call

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should mention all the class name that you want to define and assign constructor. By the way according to the given code you have two classes one is `Product` and other is `MyProduct`

```
// Product.h
Product(char type);                     
Product(const char* sku, const char* address, const char * unit, int onHand, 
int needed, double beforeTax, bool taxable);


// test.cpp
MyProduct::MyProduct() : Product("", "", "") {}
```

So, in this is not meet with constructor of `Product`.
You have need to pass one or seven parameters in `Product` constructor.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that mistake, so I updated the definition to have 4 optional defaults

     Product::Product(const char* sku, const char* address, const char * unit, int onHand = 0, int needed = 0, double beforeTax = 0.0, bool taxable = true)

but I'm still getting the same error